# apply window.hostname href for image?

Tags: jquery, image, href

if an image html is

```
<img src="img1" class="homeimage"/>
```

how using jquery would you wrap a `<a>` around the image with window.hostname as a href?

so if the url of a page is `http://www.google.com/search?jksjkjskaj`

the jquery should return

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="img1" class="homeimage"/></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out jQuery's [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap)

```
$(".homeimage").wrap("<a href='" + location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + "'></a>");
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CRN86/1/

Comment: I have edited both answers to include the protocol. `location.protocol` equals something like `http:`, location.hostname equals `stackoverflow.com`. Add both together, with a `//` in between, resulting in `http://stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: thankyou @RobW and Andrew for your contribution :D i will accept your answer when stackoverflow allows me to (4 minutes)

Comment: I have another question but i will ask it separately sorry guys i didn't think of it until now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.homeimage').wrap('<a href="' + location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '"></a>');
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead the solutions proposed above, I want to add another one:

```
$('.homeimage').wrap('<a href="' + location.origin + '"></a>');
```