# Only apply jquery if the url has a pathname

Tags: jquery, window.location

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960535/apply-window-hostname-href-for-image)

how would you apply this jquery

```
$(".homeimage").wrap("<a href='" + location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + "'></a>");
```

only if the url has a pathname for example `http://google.com/search` but dont apply the jquery if the url is `http:/google.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(window.location.pathname && window.location.pathname !== '/') {
    $(".homeimage").wrap("<a href='" + location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + "'></a>");
}
```